# How to overload operators on built-in types

Tags: python, overloading

Would it be possible to overload '>' as an operator on two strings.   This would be nice as it would allow for custom results while debugging.   In my case, I could also edit the source code and add prints, etc., but the Monkey Patch is quicker and available without a rebuild.

The desired result would be that typing (for example):

```
>>>import os
>>>"string1" > "string2"
```

would call some custom code that I've created.   Other options might be to use decorators, or some of the solutions here:

[Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: Python isn't a shell. If you want a shell, use a shell. Trying to turn Python into a crappy shell substitute is going to get you worse results than using a shell normally or using Python normally.

Comment: Do you *really* want to completely break string comparison just to get a slightly more convenient syntax for writing to files?

Comment: You cannot overload operators on built-in types.

Comment: If you want a language that encourages this kind of monkeypatching, Ruby is not hard to find. [The Python Way](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) strongly discourages things that happen behind your back and spooky action at a distance, because Python's philosophy values predictability, understandability, readability, etc. This kind of hack is very much contrary to "explicit is better than implicit", _and_ to "there should be one, and only one, obvious way to do it". It's also contrary to "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules".

Comment: (A language that's _even more_ attached to having optional special cases / several ways to do things in its syntax is Perl, and the resulting difficulty in maintaining other peoples' perl has a great deal to do with why folks flocked away from it to Python when the latter emerged as a practical alternative).

Comment: I do very much appreciate the vast concern.   Please let it be known that the risks in such endeavors are well-understood.   The question is intended in a Beazlyian context.   (See any of many PyCon presentations from David Beazley for context.)

Comment: Here is a good one from David, for example:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI

Comment: I've modified the question to address everyone's concerns.

Comment: I've further modified the question based on feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you derive a class from `str` I guess you could:

```py
class pipe_string(str):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        with open(other, "w") as file:
            file.write(self)

pipe_string("foo") > "bar.txt"
```

But I would discourage it I think. Might be better to send whatever you are looking to send to `stdout` via python and use your shell to do shell things.